# Consistent Scrolling Background

Tags: html, css

First question here so forgive me if this was already answered.

I'm trying to make a simple web page where I have a solid background and a div acting as container to put information into. I'm struggling to make the background to be consistent on all the page.

I want the yellow background to extend througout the page. The main div will act as the div containing the container div.

```css
.main{

  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  position:absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right:20px;
  top:20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border-style:solid;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        This is where the information will get shown to the user.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not much to go on, However for this **`I'm struggling to make the background to be consistent on all the page.`** Why not simply apply a background to the `<body>` ?